# Expression Blend for Visual Studio 2013 crashes when I'm trying to add a ValueChanged event for slider

Tags: visual-studio-2013, slider, expression-blend

I have a slider that I would like to change the size of an ellipse. However, when I try to add a ValueChanged event by double clicking the box with the event name in the event tab, Blend crashes.

I have also tried to manually add the event by writing the event name in the box, but when I hit enter, Blend crashes.

This is the error I get in Visual Studio when I select debug:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred  in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.
```

Comment: Share your xaml, sounds like an easy fix.I know this is an old question, but I can show you how to do it without even handling ValueChanged.

Comment: Thank you for offering help, but it's no longer a problem. Also, I no longer have the file in question.